# Change value pointed by this pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, reference

I wrote this working piece of code for my matrix struct. It computes the value of a square matrix raised to the e-th power, but this is irrelevant. I want to know what is happening in the last lines.

Is the value of p being copied to the location pointed by *this*? Is it a shallow copy or a deep copy?
Is *this* being changed? I don't think so because it's const.

How can I implement that copy to make it run faster?

```
matrix& operator ^=(int e)
{
    matrix& b = *this;
    matrix p = identity(order());
    while (e) {
        if (e & 1)
            p *= b;
        e >>= 1;
        b *= b;
    }
    *this = p;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Whether or not it's a deep or shallow copy will depend on how your `matrix` class is implemented.  Also, your method is not marked as `const` therefore `this` is not `const`.

Comment: Best use `auto&& p = identity(order());` to avoid copies. And `*this = std::move(p);` later. Anyway, why the alias for `*this`?

Comment: I forgot about `auto`, but why two references? `matrix` is not an array and `identity` returns a value. The existence of the alias is to improve readability.

Comment: @GWW: `this` is always `const`, effectively (it's actually a keyword, not an lvalue at all).  What it points to is not `const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the following will make it faster, if you're added appropriate buffer-stealing support to your class:

Replace

```
*this = p;
```

by either (preferred in C++11)

```
*this = std::move(p);
```

or (for C++03, should still work ok in C++11)

```
swap(p); // if swap is a member
swap(*this, p); // if it's not
```

<strike>However, since you can't overwrite the left hand side in place, best is to implement `operator^`, and write `operator^=` in terms of that:</strike>

```
matrix operator^(const matrix& b, int e)
{
    matrix p = identity(b.order()); // move or elision activated automatically
    while (e) {
        if (e & 1)
            p *= b;
        e >>= 1;
        b *= b;
    }
    return p; // move or NRVO activated automatically
}

matrix& operator^=(int e)
{
    *this = (*this) ^ e; // move activated automatically since RHS is temporary
    // ((*this) ^ e).swap(*this); in C++03
    return *this;
}
```

Just noticed you are overwriting `*this` in place, with successive squares.

Answer (score 0):

`*this = p;` invokes your matrix's `operator=(matrix)` method, if it has one, otherwise it invokes a compiler-generated `operator=()` that simple performs a member-by-member copy of `p`'s fields into `this`'s fields (using their respective `operator=()` implementations).